Unable to Access SecretsManager from ElasticBeanstalk Env with Valid IAM Role Permissions
I am trying to get few secrets which are required to run my python developed env deployed using Elastic Beanstalk with Python 3.11 and using Nginx Server.
Below is my code for getting secrets Manager
def getSecretValuesFor(secretName, secretClient):
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = secretClient.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secretName
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        return {'accessKey': '', 'secretAK': ''}
    return json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])

def get_secret():
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name='us-east-1'
    )

    allKeys = getSecretValuesFor('*******', client)
    accessKey = allKeys['*****']
    secretKey = allKeys['*****']

    parserKeys = getSecretValuesFor('********', client)
    parserKey = parserKeys['****']
    return accessKey, secretKey, parserKey

My Permissions on IAM ROLE used by Elastic Beanstalk (Verified in EC2 this is the exact role its referring to:
IAM ROLE SNAPSHOT
Security Group Allows Outbound to All and inbound on port 80 to all.
Inbound Rules
OUTBOUND BELOW
OUTBOUND Rules
EC2 is running in Public Subnets with IGW attached with Route Table (CONFIRMED)
Updating Rules,
Creating new IAM Role,
Setting new Env completely(Throws Connection Timed Out Error),
Accessing Keys directly from Ec2 ,
Updating Code at my end in Python.
NOTHING ABOVE HAS WORKED
ERRORS BELOW
WHEN RUNNING COMMAND IN EC2
EC2 Error
API ERROR
API ERROR

If you are getting connection timeout errors, there is some sort of network issue. Do you have any non-default Network ACL rules assigned to the VPC subnets? Do you have any VPC endpoints configured, such as a Secrets Manager VPC endpoint, that the network request could be routing to?

Vpc endpoints are required when we put the instance in private subnet, correct me if i am wrong in it.
This ebs instance work in two subnets attached to one route table which has 1 IGW pointing to 0.0.0.0 (open to all) no specific nat or nacl rules applied. also the error is connection timed out (i checked by manually ssh into instance and running to list the secrets) i have a api module deployed which accesses secrets for keys and in api response I get 504 gateway timed out.

If i have to create a vpc endpoint i can try that will that be gateway or interface? Like i have two subnets used interface provide 4 url 2 for each subnet how would i know which to use. Example instance in subnet a i used url for A (endpoint vpc) if b i would use endpoint b or any one would work for both ?

I wouldn't create a VPC endpoint. I was just trying to eliminate possible causes. Your server certainly seems to be behaving as if it is in a private subnet, not a public subnet. Have you tested any other network connectivity from that machine? Like a curl google.com or something?

curl google.com response as 301 Moved
The document has moved. So, I guess this is able to access internet outbound connection is working fine
